# Deleting folders in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I tried to delete a folder, so I tried 'DEL "%Folder%"'. That left the folder itself behind, and deleted all files within the folder. Then I typed DEL /? into the cmd prompt and read "If a directory is specified, all files within the directory will be deleted." So, what do I have to do to delete the folder itself?

Comment: What operating system?  What programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using RD or RMDIR commands. A more detailed usage description [here](http://www.computerhope.com/rmdirhlp.htm).

Syntax:

> RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
>
> RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `RMDIR "%Folder%"` to remove the directory (and sub directories with `/s` if desired).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490990.aspx